# Problems to clone anything from my github

Tags: github

When I go to clone something from my repository on GitHub this error appears just below. The only thing different was the migration from Ubuntu version 21.10 to version 22.00.

```
git clone https://github.com/CanonVortigen/ProjetoAnkiUnivesp.git
git: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This isn't a programming problem. You've just got a broken *something*. Probably you installed git from source and depend on a library file that was installed from apt, and the upgrade has upgraded the library file. Reinstall git. (Or ssh or whatever it is that got installed from source)

Comment: everything you said I already did and the problem persists, I can't download anything else because of this library